# SQL joins on joined table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

**table1**

```
out_path_id
in_path_id
other_fields
```

**table2**

```
id
name
location_to_id
location_from_id
car_id
other_fields
```

**location**

```
id
name
```

**car**

```
id
name
```

`table1`'s `out_path_id` and `in_path_id` is refer to `table2`'s `id`.

`table2`'s `location_to_id` and `location_from_id` is refer to `location`'s `id`.

`table2`'s `car_id` is refer to `car`'s `id`.

It's okay to join `table1` and `table2`.

```
select t2out.name out_name, t2in.name in_name, t1.other_fields
from table1 t1
join table2 t2out on t2out.id=t1.out_path_id
join table2 t2in on t2in.id=t1.in_path_id
```

Now I try to continue join with `location` and `car`. What can I do?

Comment: Please update the description to show what you expect the result set to look like; this is necessary to know how the joins should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below join both location and car by using their corresponding key

```
select t1.other_fields,t2.name as out_name,
     t22.name as in_name,l1.name as location_to_name
    ,l2.name as location_from_name,c.name from 
      table1 t1
      left join table2 t2 on t1.out_path_id=t2.id
      left join table2 t22 on t1.in_path=t22.id
      left join location l1 on t2.location_to_id=l1.id
      left join location l2 on t2.location_from_id=l2.id
      left join car c on t2.car_id=c.id
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems not working, it cannot find `location_from_id` belongs to which table: `ambiguous column name: location_from_id`.

Comment: How about join `table2` with `location` and `car` first, then join `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

You continue aliasing like you have.  You'll need 4 location table aliases as you have two locations in table2.  You'll need two car table aliases as you have 1 car in table 2.

```
JOIN location t2out_loc_to ON t2out.location_to_id = t2out_loc_to.id
```

and so forth